# Chrome web store - Developer Dashboard - installations count

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Developer dashboard in Chrome Web Store shows installation count for app installs differently.

For example, Web Store dashboard shows 3 intalls for 06/20.  But our database shows 10 user installs for that day.

In our database we store user id once they accept Google authentication in `onInstall` call.  But we are not tracking uninstalls of the app.  Does Web Store dashboard count both (install / uninstall) and show the result?

Also it seems that developer dashboard is not providing live data.  For 06/24 four users have installed our app (as per our database) but developer dashboard shows zero.  Does it update data by end of the day?

Comment: Just a note, you can track uninstalls using [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-setUninstallURL)

Comment: I saw the same things, installs and uninstalls are different between chrome dashboard and my db number